# Socket.io and Internet explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, websocket, socket.io

I'm having trouble with socket.io not working on internet explorer 8 and 9.

Give this error:
'this.websocket' is null or not an object
socket.io.min.js line 2

I've set the WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION this way. It is part of Jquery $(document).ready

var WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION = 'http://photosandhomes.ca/static/WebSocketMain.swf';
var page_loadSock = io.connect('/page_load');

Thank you.

PS. Here's a live example
http://photosandhomes.ca/33harbour/

Comment: Try setting WEB_SOCKET_DEBUG = true. Do you serve Flash policy file on 843?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had "var WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION" in the code.

If you're having the same problem use "WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION" without the var in the global namespace.

I personally placed WEB_SOCKET_SWF_LOCATION into the socket.io.js file.